# Best practice 10+ projects will run by using ONE container / parameterised

Tags: python, docker, sh

The idea is to have a single container which will contain all small projects and will run based on parameters.

**What is the current situation:**

I have folders with the project this way:

```
├── MAIN_PROJECT_FOLDER
│   ├── PROJECT_SUB_CATEGORY1
│   ├── ├── PROJECT_NAME_FOLDER1
│   │   │   ├── run.sh
│   │   │   ├── main.py
│   │   │   ├── config.py
│   ├── ├── PROJECT_NAME_FOLDER2
│   │   │   ├── run.sh
│   │   │   ├── main.py
│   │   │   ├── config.py
│   ├── PROJECT_SUB_CATEGORY2
│   ├── ├── PROJECT_NAME_FOLDER1
│   │   │   ├── run.sh
│   │   │   ├── main.py
│   │   │   ├── config.py
│   ├── ├── PROJECT_NAME_FOLDER2
│   │   │   ├── run.sh
│   │   │   ├── main.py
│   │   │   ├── config.py
```

Each **run.sh** file has prod/dev parameters which can be executed like this:

```
sudo ./run.sh prod = prod
sudo ./run.sh dev  = dev
sudo ./run.sh      = dev
```

What is the way to create another **.SH** file or **Dockerfile** which at the end can be executed like this:

```
sudo docker run CONTAINER_NAME PROJECT_NAME PROD/DEV
sudo docker run test_contaner test_project1 prod
sudo docker run test_contaner test_project1 dev
sudo docker run test_contaner test_project2 prod
... and so one
```

Basically, each project is the parameter and prod/dev will be part of run.sh execution somehow.

Looking for the best practice to make this happen.

Comment: You can use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/running.html) to run your projects with required parametres. All you need is to create a configuration file described as in the docs and copy them to the directory from which supervisor reads config to load.

Comment: @xbound will it be hard to have example of how it will work based on provided information?

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is generally to have an image that does only one thing.  In your example that would imply four separate Docker images; each directory would have its own Dockerfile.

It also tends to be easier to configure settings like this using environment variables than command-line parameters.  Sites like https://12factor.net/ [describe this](https://12factor.net/config) and some other practices for building services.  (In YAML specifications like Docker Compose or Kubernetes, it is easier to add another key/value environment pair than to build up a correct command line from multiple disparate parts, in my experience.)

This leads you to a sequence like

```sh
sudo docker build -t me/cat1proj1 CATEGORY_1/PROJECT_1
sudo docker run -e ENVIRONMENT=prod me/cat1proj1
```

Architecturally, the Docker container runs any single process, and absolutely nothing stops you from writing the wrapper script you describe.  That single command is specified as a combination of an "entrypoint" and a "command"; if you specify both then the command is passed as arguments to the entrypoint.  The "command" part can be specified in the Dockerfile `CMD`, but it can also be overridden at the `docker run` command line.

If you write no special scripts at all, you can run (assuming you've `COPY`d the projects to the right directories)

```sh
sudo docker run test_image ./test_project1/run.sh prod
```

(I have a couple of projects that are the same application with different scripts to start them in different ways – a Web server vs. an async job runner with the same code, for instance – and just launch them with alternate startup scripts this way.)

There is a pattern of making some other script be the `ENTRYPOINT`, and interpreting the "command" as just arguments to that script.  The command just gets passed as arguments `$1`, `$2`, `"$@"`.  The problem with doing this is that it breaks some routine debugging paths.

```sh
# "test_project1" "prod" passed as arguments to entrypoint script
sudo docker run test_image test_project1 prod

# But that breaks getting a debug shell
sudo docker run --rm -it test_image bash

# More complex commands get awkward
sudo docker run --rm --entrypoint=/bin/ls test_image -l /app
```

Comment: Thank you for the extremely useful explanation. In my circumstances `sudo docker run test_image test_project1 prod` this command line is exactly what I'm looking for. If this is possible could you explain what is the best way to have different test_project1(2,3,4,5). In docker files, I will have `COPY . /app` so all the project folders will be copied to container and here is the problem that I cannot understand how to set up that each project will be assigned to a different parameter? P.S. I have knowledge how to create project per container but not a lot of projects in a single container

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use tool like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) which can be run inside one docker container.

Installing `supervisor` on Ubuntu and Debian based distros:

```sh
sudo apt install supervisor
```

Starting `supervisor` daemon:

```sh
sudo service supervisor start
```

In `/etc/supervisord/supervisord.conf` you will find place where to put configs for your projects:

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

Now you can create configuration for supervisor and copy it to `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/`. Example `supervisor` config for project `PROJECT_1`:

`project_1_supervisor.conf`:

```
[program:project_1_app]
command=/usr/bin/bash /project_1_path/run.sh prod
directory=/project_1_path/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stderr_logfile=/var/log/project_1.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/project_1.out.log
```

After this restart your `supervisor`:

```sh
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
```

After this you can check if your project program runs:

```
$ supervisorctl
project_1_app               RUNNING    pid 590, uptime 0:02:45
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to handle this is ENV, Here is the complete example that what you are looking for.

Here is the directory structure

[image]

Here is the smartest dockerfile that clone the above app and do smart thing ;) That will take four env, by default it will run project A.

```
ENV BASE_PATH="/opt/project"
```

This ENV is for project base path during clone

```
  ENV PROJECT_PATH="/main/sub_folder_a/project_a"
```

This ENV is for project path for example Project B

`ENV SCRIPT_NAME="hello.py"`

This ENV will be used to run the actual file can be `run.sh` or `main.py` in your case.

`ENV SYSTEM_ENV=dev`

This env is used run.sh this can either `dev` or `prod`

```
FROM python:3.7.4-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /opt/project

# Required Tools
RUN apk add --no-cache supervisor git tree && \
    mkdir -p /etc/supervisord.d/

# clone remote project or copy your own one
RUN echo "Starting remote clonning...."
RUN git clone https://github.com/Adiii717/python-demo-app.git /opt/project
RUN tree /opt/project

# ENV for start different project, can be overide at run time
ENV BASE_PATH="/opt/project"
ENV PROJECT_PATH="/main/sub_folder_a/project_a"
ENV SCRIPT_NAME="hello.py"
# possible dev or prod
ENV SYSTEM_ENV=dev
RUN chmod +x /opt/project/main/*/*/run.sh
# general config
RUN echo  $'[supervisord] \n\
[unix_http_server] \n\
file = /tmp/supervisor.sock \n\
chmod = 0777 \n\
chown= nobody:nogroup \n\
[supervisord] \n\
logfile = /tmp/supervisord.log \n\
logfile_maxbytes = 50MB \n\
logfile_backups=10 \n\
loglevel = info \n\ 
pidfile = /tmp/supervisord.pid \n\
nodaemon = true \n\
umask = 022 \n\
identifier = supervisor \n\
[supervisorctl] \n\
serverurl = unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock \n\
[rpcinterface:supervisor] \n\
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface \n\
[include] \n\
files = /etc/supervisord.d/*.conf' >> /etc/supervisord.conf 
# script supervisord Config
RUN echo $'[supervisord] \n\
nodaemon=true \n\
[program:run_project ] \n\
command= /run_project.sh  \n\
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1 \n\
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0MB \n\
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0 \n\
stderr_logfile=/dev/fd/2 \n\
redirect_stderr=true \n\
autorestart=false \n\
startretries=0 \n\
exitcodes=0 ' >> /etc/supervisord.d/run_project.conf

RUN echo $'#!/bin/ash \n\
    echo -e "\x1B[31m starting project having name ${BASE_PATH}${PROJECT_PATH}/${SCRIPT_NAME}  \x1B[0m" \n\
    fullfilename=${BASE_PATH}${PROJECT_PATH}/${SCRIPT_NAME} \n\ 
    filename=$(basename "$fullfilename") \n\
    extension="${filename##*.}" \n\
if [[ ${extension} == "sh" ]];then \n\
    sh ${BASE_PATH}${PROJECT_PATH}/${SCRIPT_NAME} ${SYSTEM_ENV}  \n\ 
    else \n\
    python ${BASE_PATH}${PROJECT_PATH}/${SCRIPT_NAME} \n\
    fi '      >> /run_project.sh
RUN  chmod +x /run_project.sh


EXPOSE 9080 8000 9088 80

ENTRYPOINT ["supervisord", "--nodaemon", "--configuration", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

Build the docker image

```
docker build -t multipy .
```

Run the docker container
`docker run --rm -it multipy`

This will run `project a` by default

to project b, your command will be

`docker run --rm -it --env PROJECT_PATH=/main/sub_folder_b/project_b --env SCRIPT_NAME=hello.py  multipy`

To run your `run.sh` bash file command will be

`docker run --rm -it --env SCRIPT_NAME=run.sh  multipy`

Here is the some logs

[image]

Comment: @Oksana let me know if this need modification